# How to handle close browser activity in test series examination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, browser, crash

Currently I am working on test series project( Like GATE ), So I need to calculate the result of the test series at the end of test series or when user submit the test series.

But If browser crashed or machine shut down,How should I handle this?? 
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: log results as you go, not at the end